# Charts.js con Responsive

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, chart.js

Hola que tal? Hoy mi pregunta es a cerca de la libreria **Chart.js**; El proyecto en el cual me encuentro actualmente a implementado esta libreria en un par de módulos, por consiguiente me encomendaron la tarea de poner el **Responsive Web Design** de estos módulos, el problema comenzó cuando intenté arreglar las graficas que se utilizaron, al reducir el ancho de la página, las graficas se hacian cada vez mas pequeñas hasta el punto de ucupar el tamaño de un dedo.

No se que mas hacer, espero su divina ayuda. En caso de necesitar el código que utilicé, me lo pueden pedir. gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el **Diagrama Circular** no lo muestra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Támpoco lo muestra en el **Diagrama de Area**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Diagrama de Radar**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Diagrama Lineal**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
grafica1 = new Chart($("#vendedores"), {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: {
            labels : vendedores,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Datos',
                data: valores,
                backgroundColor: colors
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                    label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                        var tooltipValue = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index]
                        return parseFloat(tooltipValue).toLocaleString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<div style="height: 75%" id="contenidoGrafico" class="contenidoGrafico">
    <div class="row canvas">
         <canvas id="vendedores" class="vendedores col-sm-12" height="300" width="715"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ese sería el código base, en caso de necesitar más o algo en especifico me lo pueden hacer saber. gracias!

*Seguiré intentando*

Comment: Estaría bien que pusieses el código que usas, para poder ver qué pasa.

Comment: está bien, ya lo anexo

Comment: te sugiero revisar la documentacion : https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html

Comment: aca tambien tienes un ejemplo responsive: https://codepen.io/chartjs/pen/YVWZbz

Comment: Gracias @DiegoAvila